# running play framework 2.5 from intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework

I want to run a play project from Intellij console directly. But that dosn't work. Problem is the Server can't reach the mysql server ... connection timeout 
(both playframework and mysql are locally on my machine)

When I run the project from windows command line it works perfectly

what could be the reason for this?

Comment: A firewall that is process specific and blocks certain app connections?

Comment: A few questions... are you able to run your application from Intelli via a Run/Debug configuration? When you try to run your application from the console, are you following these guidelines? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/PlayConsole Are you using Activator or SBT? My projects run fine via Run/Debug as well as Activator (via my Intellij console or my normal terminal) without having to setup proxies. I started with a basic hello world app and followed those console commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting proxy . May be proxy is not set in you play framework.

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=<your proxy host>
-Dhttp.proxyPort=<your proxy port>
-Dhttps.proxyHost=<your proxy host>
-Dhttps.proxyPort=<your proxy port>
```

Comment: where should I configure them? And what should I set as proxy? localhost?

Comment: Does your PC use proxy to connect internet ? 
if so then you should enter these settings in console .

Comment: no we dont use a proxy .... restart of the machine has solved the problem